# How many watts max at my 220v L14 30R outlet?

Tags: electrical

I have a 40amp double pole breaker on my main with 30' of 8/3 to an L14 30R locking outlet, what is the max wattage?

Thank you.

Comment: What was this receptacle intended to power?

Comment: And what are you plugging into it?

Comment: Welder or a temporary distribution box. Which ever is needed in the shop at the moment.

Comment: Can you give us the I1eff from the welder's nameplate, or barring that, its input current rating and maximum duty cycle?

Answer (score 2):

0 watts.  A 30A receptacle on a 40A breaker is a code violation.

5760 watts continuous, 7200W intermittent, if you change the breaker to 30A.

7680 watts continuous, 9600W intermittent, if you change the receptacle to NEMA 14-50R.

Why are we using a NEMA 14-***50*** on a 40A circuit? They don't make 40A receptacles/plugs.  You are expected to use 50A sockets on 40A circuits. This exception is coded into NEC table 210.21(b)(3).

Comment: Where’s the 50 amp breaker?

Comment: Then why would you tell him to change the receptacle to a 14-50r?

Comment: Interesting.. I also never realized L14-40 does seem to exist.

Comment: I am going to change the breaker to a 30 amp and keep the 8/3 with the L14 30. If I change the receptacle to an L14 50, then the cable would have to be changed to a 6/3?

Comment: @JeffF. No need. 40A breaker to 8/3 to 14-50 is correct for a 40A circuit.  The reason for the 50A receptacle is they do not make 40A receptacles.

Comment: Could it be for a motor or a welder load?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel That might explain the mismatch, yeah.  The question is what OP's load will be today.  I wish they would elaborate.  I may have been hasty.

Comment: It is in a fab shop. Welder or Temporary distribution box (when using hand tools etc.) The distribution box has an l14 30 plug so I need to keep the 30amp receptacle. I already got the breaker switched to a 30 amp.

Comment: @JeffF. Oh, those are big differences in application, as such you need to follow the lowest common denominator advice, as I gave.  If a circuit is *only* a welder or *only* a motor, certain liberalizations exist.